# Textbox activates code when enter is pressed

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, key, enter

I have a two columns in excel which have corresponding items. My program needs to check textbox3 for its value and if that value exists (case insensitive) in the first column then textbox4 will take on the corresponding value. So basically the user types in the name of an item in textbox3 and presses enter (the key, not a button). If it exists then textbox4 will take on the corresponding value.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim abrv As String
        abrv = TextBox3.Text
        Sheet2.Activate
        For i = 1 To 2494
            If abrv = Range("a" & i).Value Then
                TextBox4.Text = Range("b" & i).Value
            End If
        Next i
        If TextBox4.Text = "" Then
            TextBox4.Text = "Abbreviation does not exist."
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify which sheet the range is in. Try this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 13 Then
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim abrv As String
    abrv = TextBox3.Text
    Sheet2.Activate
    For i = 1 To 2494
        If abrv = Sheet2.Range("a" & i).Value Then
            TextBox4.Text = Sheet2.Range("b" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
    If TextBox4.Text = "" Then
        TextBox4.Text = "Abbreviation does not exist."
    End If
End If
```

Also you might get an error with this:

```
 Range("a" & i)
```

If you do use this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim abrv As String
        abrv = TextBox3.Text
        Sheet2.Activate
        For i = 1 To 2494
            If abrv = Sheet2.Range("a" & strings.trim(str(i))).Value Then
                TextBox4.Text = Sheet2.Range("b" & strings.trim(str(i))).Value
            End If
        Next i
        If TextBox4.Text = "" Then
            TextBox4.Text = "Abbreviation does not exist."
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: When I click enter in the userform after typing in an abreviation the cursor moves to the next textbox instead of retrieving the corresponding value. Also, does sheet2.activate not make range look at sheet 2? Just curious about that, I have no idea how it works.

Comment: You could return focus to the previous text box using something like TextBox1.SetFocus. Sheet2.activate only brings focus to sheet2.

Comment: Thank you, the first set of code you posted works perfectly! I just forgot to change textbox1_keydown to textbox3_keydown

Comment: np, glad I could help :)